# How to fit content to modal in angular?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am initializing my modal with

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'search/profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileController as profileCtrl'
  });
```

The CSS associated with it is

```
.modal-content{
    width: 100%;
    length: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately, for modals with lots of content, the text will overflow and the modal dimensions will not match it (the white part is the modal):

[image: The white part is the modal]

How can I fit my content to the modal or fit the modal to the content? A hacky solution that I figured out was to just make the modal very large with length: 10000%, but that is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where this would go because you haven't provided enough code, but you'll need to use:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Somewhere in your CSS so the content will scroll within the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the windowTopClass option to set a class on the outer html element of the modal.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    ....
    windowTopClass: 'fullScreen'
  });
```

This is CSS I used to have a modal that completely covers the viewport.  Change #fps to something that refers to the outer element for your template, and adjust your positioning as needed.

The trick here is setting modal-content to relative, so that the #fps element, when set to absolute, will completely fill just the content part of the modal.  The top property allows for a non-scrolling part of the modal; remove that if you want all the contents to scroll.

```
/* Adjust these properties if you don't want the modal to cover the whole viewport */
    .fullScreen>.modal-dialog {
        margin:0;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .fullScreen .modal-content{
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    .fullScreen #fps {
        position:absolute;
        /* adjust this property to allow for non-scrolling elements.  they'll also need to be absolutely positioned */
        top:60px;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

Here is the template used for the modal:

```
<div id="fps" class="container-fluid">
    ... contents go here
</div>
```